# Get user input to declare a global variable (int and string) python

Tags: string, variables, python-3.x, global

I am making a life counter for MTG I would like to ask the user for the life total and their name. Then use both in the program. I have a running and functional program that uses declared values for the healt count for player 1 and 2 and label and text for the players

```
 p1hc = 20
 p2hc = 20
```

I tested setting the values with the "input" function and printing the numbers in a different window to make sure

```
 p1healthc = input (' What is the starting life count? ')
 p2healthc = input (' What is the starting life count? ')

 print (p1healthc)
 print (p1healthc)
```

When I added the code to my running and working program with

### Declare global health count values for player 1 and player 2 variables

```
 p1healthc = input (' What is the starting life count? ')
 p2healthc = input (' What is the starting life count? ')
 p1hc = p1healthc
 p2hc = p2healthc
```

It would ask for the and set the values in the SHELL window and not start the program window after.

Comment: What programming language are you using?  What SHELL is it?

Comment: I am using the newest python and the tkinter stuff

Comment: Try to convert the input like `p1hc = int(p1healthc)`

Comment: Michel's comment is correct, but you said many things without asking a question.  Please edit to say what you are asking for.